# Applescript set window bounds for all windows

Tags: macos, applescript

I modified some AppleScript I found a while ago to position the frontmost window in a way so there is about a 10px margin on each side from the edge of the screen/dock/menubar:

```
set front_app to (path to frontmost application as Unicode text)

tell application "Finder"
    set _b to bounds of window of desktop
    set scrn_width to item 3 of _b
    set scrn_height to item 4 of _b
end tell

tell application front_app
    activate
    set bounds of window 1 to {10, 35, (scrnWidth - 10), (scrnHeight - 80)}
end tell
```

The problem is I have to do it for each window individually. I'd like to just run it once and have it work on all the windows of each application.

I've tried modifying around 5 different scripts but just get errors. Here is what I have:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Finder"
        set _b to bounds of window of desktop
        set scrn_width to item 3 of _b
        set scrn_height to item 4 of _b
    end tell
    set _windows to get windows of (application processes whose visible is true)
    repeat with this_window in (items of _windows)
        set bounds of this_window to {10, 35, (scrn_width - 10), (scrn_height - 80)}
    end repeat
end tell
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of work, here's what I came up with.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmostApps to every process whose frontmost is true
    if ((count of frontmostApps) = 0) then return
    set frontmostAppAlias to application file of (item 1 of frontmostApps)
end tell

tell application "Finder" to set desktopBounds to bounds of window of desktop

set screenWidth to item 3 of desktopBounds
set screenHeight to item 4 of desktopBounds

tell application (frontmostAppAlias as string)
    set resizableAppWindows to every window whose resizable is true
    repeat with i from 1 to (count of resizableAppWindows)
        set appWindow to item i of resizableAppWindows
        set bounds of appWindow to {10, 35, (screenWidth - 10), (screenHeight - 80)}
    end repeat
end tell
```

I originally started off trying to do everything within a `tell app "System Events"` block, but found that the `window`s of `application process`es don't seem to allow the same calls as normal `window`s, even though from the scripting definition they should. That led to the `tell` block directly to the app itself.

You may want to wrap the `set bounds` in a `try` block, since there will likely be some apps that have a resizable window that has a maximum size limitation set, which could cause an error.

Comment: Thank you! I modified it slightly so that it would loop through all the open apps (which took a while, haha -- I'm not great at AppleScript). https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5020503